# How to show Product Custom Attribute in edit page of Credit Memos, Invoice and Shipments below SKU in admin in Magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2, sales

I want to show Product Custom Attribute in edit page of Invoice, Shipments and  Credit Memos below SKU in admin in Magento2.2.0? 
Refer my Screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module with name STech_Salesattribute by following below steps:

**Step 1:** Create **registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/Salesattribute/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Salesattribute',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:** Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Salesattribute/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Salesattribute" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create **adminhtml_order_shipment_new.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Salesattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Salesattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 4:** Create **sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Salesattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Salesattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 5:** Create **sales_order_invoice_new.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Salesattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Salesattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 6:** Create **name.phtml** under

> app/code/STech/Salesattribute/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml

```
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?= implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['value'] ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid() ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id = 'id' . uniqid() ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php //Your code starts to show custom attribute value ?>
    <dl class="item-options">
        <dt><?= __('Custom Label') ?>:</dt>
        <dd><?= $_item->getProduct()->getCustom() ?></dd>
    </dl>
    <?php //Your code ends to show custom attribute value ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thats it!. Now run setup upgrade and other required commands and check. Don't forget to replace your attribute code in place of "custom".

Comment: I have one more doubt,  your code is perfecting working for simple product. But for Bundle product the Custom attribute is not showing and for Configurable product the Custom attribute is showing only for the main product. Do you know any idea regarding this.

Comment: You need to check the product ID, if its bundle then you need to put condition and load the product accordingly

Comment: how to override invoice pdf in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of override invoice file in a custom module

Create `sales_order_invoice_new`, `sales_order_invoice_updateqty`, `sales_order_invoice_view`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items.default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now override 
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml`

to

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view//adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml`

Here in `default.phtml` you need to load full product object by product id `$_item->getProductId()` and get custom attribute value

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item)?>
    <td class="col-product"><?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?></td>
    <?php
    // Load product by $_item->getProductId() and get custom attribute value here */
    ?>
    <td class="col-price">
        <?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, 'price') ?>
    </td>
```

**For creditmemo override**

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml

**For shipment override**

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml

Comment: Thanks friend,  but the other answer is working for me. thanks for your support:)

Comment: How to show Product Custom Attribute in invoice pdf of  Magento2.2.0?